# OnLocationChanged not fired on some devices

Tags: android, gps, location, android-location, locationlistener

I'm aware that there's a lot of 'similar' questions, but none of them provided a useful answer.

I am trying to listen to location updates, both from network and GPS. The `LocationListener` initialization is pretty standard:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 15000, 0, locationListener);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 15000, 0, locationListener);
```

I tested it on two devices, Samsung Galaxy S4 (SM-N910F) and LG G Flex 2 (H950). On the first device `onLocationChanged` is called as expected (only from 'network' provider), while the event is never fired on the second.

Both devices are set on 'High Accuracy' mode. I tried the second device on Wi-Fi as well as on 4G LTE connection. Since I use Google Maps API, I can clearly see the user marker moving on map, yet the event is never called.

Any idea why `onLocationUpdated` is never called on the second device?

Additionally, I read that GPS takes a very long time to fix. Is there any point in requesting updates from the GPS provider?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest you start using Google Play location APIs.

> The Google Play services location APIs are preferred over the Android
>   framework location APIs (android.location) as a way of adding location
>   awareness to your app. If you are currently using the Android
>   framework location APIs, you are strongly encouraged to switch to the
>   Google Play services location APIs as soon as possible.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html